# Open Nuget Pkg on Local Disk

Tags: nuget-package

I'm trying to open NuGet packages of code used with the book Pro ASP MVC 5.  As I need to work offline at times, I downloaded the packages to my PC disk. How can I open these packages in VS2013.  I've tried to use the Package Manager Console -> Install-Package C:\ Wrox.ProMvc5.Views.AlbumList.1.0.0.0.nupkg (I move the package to the root of C:) Also tried enclosing string in quotes

I get this error:

```
  install-package : Unable to find package 'C:\Wrox.ProMvc5.Views.AlbumList.1.0.0.0.nupkg'.
  At line:1 char:2
  +  install-package C:\Wrox.ProMvc5.Views.AlbumList.1.0.0.0.nupkg
  +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId :       
   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is interested: you have to go to the NuGet package manager "settings" and add a new "Package Sources". I.E. "C:\myNuGetFolder". Then back in the manager, you'll see this listed and by selecting it you'll see the packages for this book if you've placed them in that folder.